# Parse.com iOS SDK crash: PFSQLiteDatabase.m line 178 -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, crash, local-datastore

I have an application in production that uses Parse.com iOS SDK with local datastore (`[PFObject pin]`).

Some of our users are getting this crash in production, as we see by the Crashlytics report for the crashing thread:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.parse.sqlite.db.queue
0  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b269f58 (null) + 9096
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b25315c (null) + 85124
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b25315c (null) + 85124
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b21bd68 (null) + 3028
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b2530c0 (null) + 84968
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b245848 (null) + 29552
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b225794 (null) + 13080
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b224634 (null) + 8632
8  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b223734 (null) + 4792
9  libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b222fa4 (null) + 2856
10 libsqlite3.dylib               0x000000019b222c5c (null) + 2016
11 Parse                          0x00000001009a9c20 -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] (PFSQLiteDatabase.m:178)
12 Bolts                          0x000000010061d034 __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke_2 (BFTask.m:334)
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019b5457b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019b545770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019b55175c _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019b549274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019b545770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019b553bb0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019b55334c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019b759478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
```

My assumption is that this happens when the DB schema changes between application upgrades, but that is almost pure guess.

What I am looking for is to see if anyone knows of any way to prevent this crash from happening, by catching the exception maybe or by setting some SDK configuration properties.

Our pinned objects are just for catching data and user sessions and could be safely deleted if required.

#### Update: Nov 23 2015

We keep experiencing this issue with the Parse SDK (1.9.1) on application launches. It seems like when the data model changes on the Parse.com backend and differs from the data model of the pinned objects, the application always crashes once. The next time it runs, everything works fine.

Possible steps to reproduce (not 100% sure):

1. Load objects from Parse.com
2. Pin objects locally
3. Close the application entirely
4. Update model in Parse.com by adding a new column
5. Launch the application
6. Repeat steps 1 and 2
7. **CRASH**
8. Launch the application again
9. Repeat steps 1 and 2
10. Everything works fine

Here is another crash report that might help debugging the issue:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.parse.sqlite.db.queue
0  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19ac05f58 (null) + 9096
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abdc020 (null) + 6984
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abdc020 (null) + 6984
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abdbe2c (null) + 6484
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abc1cc0 (null) + 14404
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abc0634 (null) + 8632
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abbf734 (null) + 4792
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abbefa4 (null) + 2856
8  libsqlite3.dylib               0x19abbec5c (null) + 2016
9  Parse                          0x100de8bc8 -[PFSQLiteDatabase _executeQueryAsync:withArgumentsInArray:cachingEnabled:] (PFSQLiteDatabase.m:176)
10 Bolts                          0x1006c6fec __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke_2 (BFTask.m:336)
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x19aee17b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x19aee1770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x19aeed75c _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x19aee5274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x19aee1770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x19aeefbb0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x19aeef34c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19b0f5478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19b0f5028 start_wqthread + 4
```

Another one:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.parse.sqlite.db.queue
0  libsqlite3.dylib               0x195959bb8 (null) + 31936
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x195959bb4 (null) + 31932
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x195952108 sqlite3_step + 528
3  Parse                          0x100e7e330 -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult step] (PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.m:39)
4  Parse                          0x100e7e2ec -[PFSQLiteDatabaseResult next] (PFSQLiteDatabaseResult.m:35)
5  Parse                          0x100e59ce4 __52-[PFOfflineStore _getPointerAsyncWithUUID:database:]_block_invoke (PFOfflineStore.m:897)
6  Bolts                          0x100727748 __62-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:successBlock:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke (BFTask.m:410)
7  Bolts                          0x100726fec __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke_2 (BFTask.m:336)
8  Bolts                          0x100724d5c __29+[BFExecutor defaultExecutor]_block_invoke_2 (BFExecutor.m:45)
9  Bolts                          0x100725270 -[BFExecutor execute:] (BFExecutor.m:109)
10 Bolts                          0x100726f64 __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke (BFTask.m:328)
11 Bolts                          0x100726b70 -[BFTask runContinuations] (BFTask.m:308)
12 Bolts                          0x1007263e0 -[BFTask trySetResult:] (BFTask.m:200)
13 Bolts                          0x100726314 -[BFTask setResult:] (BFTask.m:187)
14 Bolts                          0x100727e4c -[BFTaskCompletionSource setResult:] (BFTaskCompletionSource.m:52)
15 Bolts                          0x1007272ac __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke_3 (BFTask.m:352)
16 Bolts                          0x1007270a0 __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke_2 (BFTask.m:360)
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x195c313ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x195c3136c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x195c3b4c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1216
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x195c34474 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x195c3d224 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x195c3e75c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x195e0d2e4 _pthread_wqthread + 816
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x195e0cfa8 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Also seeing this crash and am also using using pinning for caching.  No ideas yet.

Comment: Same issue for me .... using cocoapods ! and using pinning.

Answer (score 0):

update parse sdk to latest and also avoid using cocapods try installing it manually . Cocca pods arents as stable as bower for js .

Comment: I don't see how Cocoa Pods would be related. The crash happens at runtime when the Parse.com schema changes.